# Collections organized in memory

Tags: java, arrays, memory

I have some questions regarding different collection in memory.

1. Are Map, List, Set stored differently in the memory or all the same because they are all backed up by arrays?
2. Assuming I have an ArrayList. Will the array backing it up completely moved, if the allocated block cannot be expanded any more?
3. If I swap two objects in an array, will the references be swapped using some spare memory (I think so)?
4. Does an array backing up a Map, contain 2 references per entry (key and value)?

I am sorry, if this is a duplicate, but I couldn't find answers to these questions. If you can provide some websites which have answers, I'd be happy as well. Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look to http://java-performance.info/memory-consumption-of-java-data-types-2/

Comment: @SauliusNext ill have a look at it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are Map, List, Set stored differently in the memory or all the same because they are all backed up by arrays?

They are **not** all backed by arrays

> Assuming I have an ArrayList. Will the array backing it up completely moved, if the allocated block cannot be expanded any more?

If the array is not large enough, a new one is allocated and the content of the old one copied to the new one. The old one becomes eligible to GC.

> If I swap two objects in an array, will the references be swapped using some spare memory (I think so)?

I don't understand what you mean.

> Does an array backing up a Map, contain 2 references per entry (key and value)?

A Map contains map entries, which indeed needs two references to hold the key and the value.

I suggest you read the javadoc, and aven maybe the code, of the collections you're interested into. All this is freely available.

Comment: Which are not backed up by an array? And how are they then stored in memory? Assuming you have 2 `int` and you would want to swap the values by hand, you would mostly create a third `int` to store one of the values while swapping.

Comment: emptyList, emptySet, emptyMap, singletonList, singletonSet, singletonMap, LinkedList, TreeSet, TreeMap, EnumSet, EnumMap, probably others. HashMap and HashSet use an array, + linked lists or trees. If you use a temp variable to hold a reference to an object for a swap, then this temp reference is stored on the stack, like any other local variable.

Comment: Regarding my first question, it was not about emptyList and such, only about a default Map, List, Set

Comment: There is no default Map, List, Set. These are interfaces.